Flask sqlaclhemy db relationship not populating the other table in sqlite
I am new to flask and flask-sqlalchemy. I have created one table using below code.
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite3'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
# db.init_app()

class Customer(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    address = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
    city = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    postcode = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)

    orders = db.relationship('Order', backref='customer')

order_product = db.Table('order_product',
                         db.Column('order_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('order.id'), primary_key=True),
                         db.Column('product_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('product.id'), primary_key=True)                         
)

class Order(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    order_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    shipped_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    delivered_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    coupon_code = db.Column(db.String(50))
    customer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('customer.id'), nullable=False)
    products = db.relationship('Product', secondary=order_product)

class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

Now when I am executing the db.create_all() tables are getting created in sqllite but what I am getting in sqlite is below table structure.
sqlite> .schema order
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "order" (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        order_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
        shipped_date DATETIME,
        delivered_date DATETIME,
        coupon_code VARCHAR(50),
        customer_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        FOREIGN KEY(customer_id) REFERENCES customer (id)
);

Ideally I should have got products also in the table structure.
I drop the tables using db.drop_all() and then re-creating it by using db.create_all().. I am expecting the table should have one more column as products

I just tested your code, and it seems to work fine - I can open the resultant database in SQLiteStudio and see all the tables.  When you execute '.schema order' it should only show the order table - what happens if you just type '.schema'?  Cheers, Steve

It seems that the issue you're encountering with migrations in SQLAlchemy is normal given your configuration.
The order_product table is used to manage the many-to-many relationship between Orders and Products. This intermediary table is where you should see the relationships between orders and products, not directly in the Order table.
I hope this clarifies the situation!
